# Using Show-ListView to Display a Dynamic Number of Columns in Sitecore Powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions, module

My goal is to use the **Show-ListView** function available in Sitecore Powershell to show a dynamic number of columns. I'm currently executing the Show-ListView function as follows:

```
$table |
    Show-ListView @props -Property @{ Label = "Item"; Expression = { $_.Item} },
    @{ Label = "Page Type"; Expression = { $_.PageType } },
    @{ Label = "Path"; Expression = { $_.Path} },
    @{ Label = "en"; Expression = { $_.'en' } },
    @{ Label = "en-AU"; Expression = { $_.'en-au' } },
    @{ Label = "en-CA"; Expression = { $_.'en-ca' } },
    @{ Label = "en-GB"; Expression = { $_.'en-gb' } },
    @{ Label = "en-IN"; Expression = { $_.'en-in' } },
    @{ Label = "en-SG"; Expression = { $_.'en-sg' } },
    @{ Label = "fr-CA"; Expression = { $_.'fr-ca' } },
    @{ Label = "ja-JP"; Expression = { $_.'ja-jp' } },
    @{ Label = "zh-CN"; Expression = { $_.'zh-cn' } }
```

I'd like for the list of languages printed to be dynamic based on input I'm gathering from the user. I've already successfully read in the user input using the `Read-Variable` function but I'm not sure if there is a way to use this list to dynamically generate columns.

Is this possible using the built-in Sitecore Powershell functions or does the column generation have to be exclusively static?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible to dynamically render the fields in the **Show-ListView**. You can read more from the article I posted: [Sitecore Powershell Dynamic UI](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2018/06/30/sitecore-powershell-dynamic-ui/).

Based on your current requirement, I have assumed that the `Read-Variables` takes as input a list of language. Below is a code snippet that split the languages and then create a pattern.

```
$result = Read-Variable -Parameters `
    @{ Name = "inputLanguages"; Value=""; Title="Text"; Tab="Language"; Placeholder="Input Languages delimited by ,"} `
    -Description "Language Options" `
    -Title "SSE Question" -Width 650 -Height 700 -OkButtonName "Proceed" -CancelButtonName "Abort" -ShowHints

if($result -ne "ok")
{
    Exit
}

$pattern = ""

$languages = $inputLanguages -split ","
$counter = 1

foreach($language in $languages){

    if($languages.length -eq $counter){
        $pattern += '@{ Label = "'+$language+'"; Expression = { $_."'+$language.ToLower()+'" }; }'
    }
    else{
        $pattern += '@{ Label = "'+$language+'"; Expression = { $_."'+$language.ToLower()+'" }; },'
    }

    $counter++
}

$convertPattern = Invoke-Expression $pattern


Get-ChildItem -Path "master:\sitecore\content\Home" | Show-ListView -Property $convertPattern
```

The outcome is shown in the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!